# Strange behaviour in jackson ObjectMapper in Spring MVC application with @JsonIdentityInfo

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson, objectmapper

I'm a bit confused about those things I currently see in our Spring MVC application and I hope someone can tell me what we're making wrong. Since google doesn't have an answer for me I'm sure we're making wrong.

We've a simple Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE application. Nothing special to mention about it. There is a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter configured to deliver JSON to the clients in RestControllers via Jackson ObjectMapper.

All entities which get serialized via jackson have the following annotation on tpe level

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@jsonObjectId")
```

Now the strange part:

There is a spring integration test which does the following (objectMapper gets autowired from the web application context, it is the same instance which converts the request paylod)

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dummy) // generate json from dummy object
mockMvc.perform(post(...)) // make a post request with JSON payload generated
evaluate reponse
```

Executing the test once is okay. If I copy that test case and execute it twice then I get a 400 from the server back saying IllegalArgumentExecption -> Already had POJO for id ... Problem can be reproduced in real world application so it seems to be no test problem.

I've figured out, that on serialization process the IntSequenceGenerator which is in charge of generating the "jsonObjectId" properties gets created every time an object needs to be serialized. Ok so far. But the corrresponding counterpart, in our case the default used SimpleObjectIdResolver from jackson is always the same instance. So the second server request (the second deserialization process) leads to that exception in SimpleObjectIdResolver.

I would be very thankful if anybody could give me a hint, what we're making wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to mention: Jackson-Core 2.4.1 was used. We now upgraded to version 2.7.0 of jackson and the SimpleObjectIdResolver now gets recreated for every deserialization. This seemed to be a bug in jackson before 2.7.0.

Edit: I was able to reduce the issue to the following small test:

```
public class DummyTest {

private Dummy dummy = new Dummy();

@Before
public void setUp() {
    dummy.setFoo("Foo");
}

@Test
public void testApp() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String dummyAsJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(dummy);

    mapper.readValue(dummyAsJsonString, Dummy.class);
    mapper.readValue(dummyAsJsonString, Dummy.class);
}
}
```

where Dummy.class is defined as

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@jsonObjectId")
public class Dummy {

private String foo;

public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}

public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}

}
```

You will get an IllegalStateException when executing it with jackson 2.4.1

Comment: Hello Ansgar, I Know that the version before of 2.7.0 has some bug with hash array and string, do you have your trace error?